# How do I create an encrypted mountable read/write disk image under windows?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, disk-encryption, disk-image

I know that in linux and osx it's easy to create a disk image that is encrypted and (given you know the key) can be mounted and you can read/write its content.

Under windows there are plenty of tools to encrypt single files, I also know how to create encrypted read-only iso but I need a way to create an image (let's say 10GB iso file) that once mounted behaves like a normal folder and applications can read/write in it without knowing that it's encrypted. Encryption must be transparent to the applications.

PS: I've mentioned "iso" but it's not really important what format the disk image will be.

Comment: I would just use a `TrueCrypt` container is the best method.

Comment: @Ramhound Sadly `TrueCrypt` project has been discontinued, on their page it says "WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues. This page exists only to help migrate existing data encrypted by TrueCrypt."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ProxyCrypt` http://reboot.pro/topic/19128-proxycrypt/ which is free and does exactly what I need. It's not really "famous", and I won't probably trust it for a production environment but it's an active project and for a paranoid private user is fine.

Answer (score 1):

True crypt container is one of best method,otherwise I think use **BestCrypt Container Encryption**  is also good.
if encrypted file containers with TrueCrypt, you can replaced by BestCrypt Container Encryption.

for more information [here](https://www.jetico.com/support/faq/bestcrypt-faq)